# Sign DKIM on relay mail server

Tags: dkim

I found some email have header:

```
Received: by 10.112.172.99 with SMTP id bb3csp690725lbc;
        Fri, 8 Jan 2016 11:37:33 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.55.15.139 with SMTP id 11mr615164qkp.50.1452281853620;
        Fri, 08 Jan 2016 11:37:33 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <0000015222be70c9-0079c50c-5c19-41ad-b815-86502cf31b8d-000000@amazonses.com>
Received: from a10-119.smtp-out.amazonses.com (a10-119.smtp-out.amazonses.com. [54.240.10.119])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id n66si46826200qgn.37.2016.01.08.11.37.33
        for <duongbavan49@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA bits=128/128);
        Fri, 08 Jan 2016 11:37:33 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of 0000015222be70c9-0079c50c-5c19-41ad-b815-86502cf31b8d-000000@amazonses.com designates 54.240.10.119 as permitted sender) client-ip=54.240.10.119;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of 0000015222be70c9-0079c50c-5c19-41ad-b815-86502cf31b8d-000000@amazonses.com designates 54.240.10.119 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=0000015222be70c9-0079c50c-5c19-41ad-b815-86502cf31b8d-000000@amazonses.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@coursera.org;
       dkim=pass header.i=@amazonses.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple;
    s=dnkypy6vrtp6eik6p2aszn3t5yznsvsj; d=coursera.org; t=1452281852;
    h=From:To:Subject:MIME-Version:Content-Type:Message-ID:Date;
    bh=snqI6rZAfMBFxbdRju6FEq8tdt1dUOHybmXwIYisQFk=;
    b=D5ApCCMIfK9+5tiyrqpz6B8RxkFCxoEPcEAD1evkb6SLp5jnAcb0GmX9Ilutyvqh
    kow+9hT0tuV6IV2Ut04wSsYsS9NPBBXo/3lK01LPZSts8DhrVCFT7dR9fVc81A3loYb
    NPNvADua/8zh8YW05e4kCi1UpsY9gwPOktkR26Is=
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple;
    s=ug7nbtf4gccmlpwj322ax3p6ow6yfsug; d=amazonses.com; t=1452281852;
    h=From:To:Subject:MIME-Version:Content-Type:Message-ID:Date:Feedback-ID;
    bh=snqI6rZAfMBFxbdRju6FEq8tdt1dUOHybmXwIYisQFk=;
    b=rnQ25/ZPUfxen9gy6MfaPwYtk1qJR1S3EwkSZWR7UGgEr+UTwGhhnKz/6SogAYs4
    aOu5sUR4FcFaPVkeTboyytx1wkXmoVXlXhnlsTbUw8xLKQTFpRRaVV+F7m52Gf95lkz
    FbKuBa+qARfhM/zE4VO7c/oIxBGpqNselpeY5qcY=
```

DKIM sign on:

dkim=pass header.i=@coursera.org

dkim=pass header.i=@amazonses.com

My mail server diagram:
[image: Mail diagram]

How to deploy with my diagram sign DKIM on all mail on original server and on relay server?

Answer (score 3):

You can set up DKIM on the outgoing mail server if you control it.  It depends on exactly what mail server you are using.  With postfix, you can set up an opendkim milter to inject the header into outgoing emails.

Comment: In my case, On original mail server will sign dkim outgoing mail. All email will send thought 1 relay mail server. These emails will also sign dkim of relay server mail sign. Any solution for it such as using postfix.
Thanks Jayen

Comment: Do you have control over the relay server?  Does an opendkim-postifx milter not add the header?  I think that in coursera/amazon's case, amazon's outgoing server is adding dkim headers for both domains, not any relay server.

Comment: Sorry my description not clearly. Header email above is example. I want to deploy my relay can sign dkim same it.

Comment: You can set up an opendkim milter on a postfix relay.